# Aggregate to Get totals of key value pairs in array, grouping on the field values for names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents that are structured like below, where each array element contains "k" and "v" as the key and value for different types of data. I need to group this by the "k" values for "facility", "ip" and "num" in combination and count the total distinct combination from the collection.

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "logs" : [
        { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
        { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 },
        { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.151.104" },
        { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "55902/udp" },
        { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" } 
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "logs" : [ 
        { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 }, 
        { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 },
        { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" }, 
        { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "13438/tcp" }, 
        { "n" : "port", "v" : "13438" } 
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 3,
    "logs" : [
        { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
        { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 }, 
        { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" }, 
        { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "13434/tcp" },
        { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" } 
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 4,
    "logs" : [
        { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
        { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 }, 
        { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.184" },
        { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "61662/udp" },
        { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" } 
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 5, 
    "logs" : [ 
        { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
        { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 }, 
        { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" }, 
        { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "13435/tcp" }, 
        { "n" : "port", "v" : "13435" } 
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 6,
    "logs" : [ 
        { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
        { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 },
        { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" },
        { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "61662/udp" },
        { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" }
    ]
```

}

The Query selection conditions I wan't are:

1. port is 53
2. protocol is 'udp' or 'tcp'
3. Group by [facility, num, ip]

That should select four of the six documents there. That part is working

I want a result like this.

```
{facility : 26, num : 6, ip : 137.68.151.104 , count : 1}
{facility : 26, num : 6, ip : 137.68.160.51 , count : 2}
{facility : 26, num : 6, ip : 137.68.160:184 , count : 1}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
db.agg.aggregate ([
{
'$match' : { 'logs' : {'$all' : [{'$elemMatch' : {'n' : "port", "v" : "53"}}, {'$elemMatch' : {'n' : "protocol", "v" : {"$in" :[/udp/,/tcp/]}}}   ]}}     },
{ '$unwind' : '$logs' },
{ '$match' : {"logs.n" : "ip"}},
{ '$group' : { _id : { 'ip' : '$logs.v'}, count : {$sum : 1}}}
])
```

But I don't know how to get all the fields in there, and I currently only get a result for "ip".

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below :

```
db.exp.aggregate([
 { $match : { logs : {"$all" : [{"$elemMatch" : 
           {"n" : "port", "v" : "53"}
 }, 
 { "$elemMatch" : {"n" : "protocol", "v" : {"$in" :[/udp/,/tcp/]}}}]}}
 },
 { $unwind: "$logs"},
 { $project: { facility : 
                { $cond:
                  { if :{ $eq: [ "$logs.n", "facility" ] }, 
                    then : "$logs.v", else : null}} , 
                      num : {$cond:{if : { $eq:  [ "$logs.n", "num" ] }, 
                    then : "$logs.v", else : null}}, 
                      ip : {$cond:{if : { $eq: [ "$logs.n", "ip" ] }, 
                    then : "$logs.v", else : null}} } },
 { $group: {_id:"$_id" , facility : {"$max" : "$facility"},
           num : {"$max": "$num"} , ip : {"$max" : "$ip"}}
 },
 { $group : {_id: {facility :"$facility" , 
           num : "$num" , ip : "$ip"} , count : {"$sum":1}}
 }
    ]);
```

The above query will fetch you the desired result:

```
{ "_id" : { "facility" :26, "num" : 6,
    "ip" : "137.68.151.104" }, "count" : 1 
}
{ "_id" : { "facility" : 26, "num" : 6,
    "ip" : "137.68.160.51" }, "count" : 2 
}
{ "_id" : { "facility" : 26, "num" : 6,
    "ip" : "137.68.160.184" }, "count" : 1 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your logic went wrong where you tried to match after [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Since the items are no longer in an array, then you need to match all of the key values you require as fields.

Then you transform them into fields via the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator and some creative grouping:

```js
db.agg.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
       "logs" : {
           "$all": [
               { "$elemMatch": { "n": "port", "v": "53" } },
               { "$elemMatch": { "n": "protocol", "v": { "$in" :[/udp/,/tcp/] } } }
           ]
       }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$logs" },
    { "$match": { "logs.n": { "$in": ["ip","facility","num"] } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "facility": {
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$logs.n", "facility" ] },
                    "$logs.v",
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
        "ip": {
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$logs.n", "ip" ] },
                    "$logs.v",
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
        "num": {
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$logs.n", "num" ] },
                    "$logs.v",
                    false
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
       "_id": {
           "facility": "$facility",
           "ip": "$ip",
           "num": "$num"
       },
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
 ])
```

The [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) accumulators are used to dicard the `false` values, leaving only the desired value for the "field".

Which gives the result:

```js
{ "_id" : { "facility" : 26, "ip" : "137.68.151.104", "num" : 6 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "facility" : 26, "ip" : "137.68.160.184", "num" : 6 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "facility" : 26, "ip" : "137.68.160.51", "num" : 6 }, "count" : 2 }
```